# R/dyplr: Read all CSV files in folder, append to new file if entry does not exist

Tags: r, csv, file

I have a folder with csv files for different years with a unique ID number and additional columns, e.g.:

```
Year 1:
ID V1 V2
1  A  G
2  F  D
3  S  W
4  Z  N

Year 2:
ID V1 V2
20 A  G
2  F  D
4  S  W
12 Z  N
```

Sometimes, entries (`ID`) appear in both years, as for IDs 2 and 4 in my example.

I want to do the following for every csv in my folder:

- (0) Create new data frame (`df`))
- 1) Read the csv
- 2) For each line in csv, check if an entry with that ID exists already in `df`
- 2a) If it doesn't: create the entry
- 2b) If it does: skip
- 3) At the end: Write the complete csv file

In my example, the output should be:

```
Combined:
ID V1 V2
1  A  G
2  F  D
3  S  W
4  Z  N
12 Z  N
20 A  G
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

path <- "path to folder with csv files"
```

We extract all csv files and use the `full.names` argument to show full path

```
csv_names <- list.files(path = path,
                       pattern = "*.csv",
                       full.names = TRUE)
```

Read in all csv files, combine them, extract all distinct rows and arrange them by ID.

```
df <- lapply(csv_names, read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: If you're going into `dplyr` (and since you're including the behemoth meta-package `tidyverse`, you might as well use `purrr::map` in place of `lapply`. It doesn't add any capability but is consistent with the package ecosystem :-)

Comment: A bad habit of mine. I've replaced `tidyverse` with `readr` and `dplyr`, probably better than loading `tidyverse`.

Comment: I don't have `tidyverse` installed, even though I have and use many of its packages regularly (namely `dplyr` and `tidyr`). I'm fortunate in that I know where most of the functions within tidyverse reside, and if not it's not hard to find them ... but many users aren't as comfortable with where or how to look for that information. Thanks for reduce your `library` loading :-)

Comment: Sorry for the change in specification, but is there a way to combine two files whose varibables types is not the same, i.e.: creating a table that looks like: <1, 2, 4> <A, D, 4>, <3, 3, F>?

Comment: If you can update the question, I can change my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

This is two questions.

1. Read in frames from multiple files.

   ```r
   years <- sapply(list.files(".", pattern = "year.*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE),
                   read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, simplify = FALSE)
   ```

   Since I don't have files handy, I'll just mimick that in code:

   ```r
   y1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
   ID V1 V2
   1  A  G
   2  F  D
   3  S  W
   4  Z  N")
   y2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
   ID V1 V2
   20 A  G
   2  F  D
   4  S  W
   12 Z  N")
   years <- list(year1.csv = y1, year2.csv = y2)
   ```
2. Combine with unique `ID` only:

   ```r
   useIDs <- Reduce(function(nms, x) setdiff(x[["ID"]], nms),
                    years, init = character(0), accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
   useIDs
   # [[1]]
   # [1] 1 2 3 4
   # [[2]]
   # [1] 20 12

   years2 <- Map(function(x, ids) x[ x$ID %in% ids,, drop = FALSE],
                 years, useIDs)
   years2
   # $year1.csv
   #   ID V1 V2
   # 1  1  A  G
   # 2  2  F  D
   # 3  3  S  W
   # 4  4  Z  N
   # $year2.csv
   #   ID V1 V2
   # 1 20  A  G
   # 4 12  Z  N

   do.call(rbind, c(years2, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
   #             ID V1 V2
   # year1.csv.1  1  A  G
   # year1.csv.2  2  F  D
   # year1.csv.3  3  S  W
   # year1.csv.4  4  Z  N
   # year2.csv.1 20  A  G
   # year2.csv.4 12  Z  N
   ```